# React - map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

The idea is to fetch cards that user used in the database and compare with the all cards that are listen on screen. Basically user is not supposed to see cards which he already used.

```
const loadSaveInvestments = async (
    _req: express.Request,
    res: express.Response
  ) => {
    const findSaveInvestments = await prisma.investmentSave.findMany({
      select: {
        investment_id: true,
      },
    });
    if (!findSaveInvestments) throw new HttpException(400, SAVE_INVEST_MISSING);
    res.send(findSaveInvestments);
  };
```

So, I'm sending all of the saved investment cards. Now, in the React - I'm fetching the sent data from the service (all cards and saved cards)

```
const fetchUserSaveInvestments = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/investments-save`);
  return res;
};
```

```
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
const [saveCards, setSaveCards] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);

    investService.fetchUserSaveInvestments().then((res) => {
      setSaveCards(res.data);
    });

    investService.fetchCards().then((res) => {
      setCards(res.data.investments);
      setLoading(false);
    });
```

Now - the main part. I want to map card only if it's id is not in the save cards state, so I've tried something like that.. I've marked the point where I got kinda stuck, I mean, am I supposed to create something like double map or what? Idk if I'm going in the right direction.

```
      <div className={classes.CardsContainer}>
        <div className={classes.CardsSelector}>
          {loading && <p> its loading </p>}
          {!loading && (
            <>
              {cards
                .filter(
                  (card) => card.id !== saveCards.?????.investments_id
                )
                .map((card) => (
                  <Card
                    {...card}
                    handleClick={() => handleChooseCard(card)}
                  />
                ))}
            </>
          )}
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually need `saveCards` for anything other than the `id` filtering?

Comment: Do you need the cards or saved cards? or just want a list of cards the user currently does not have saved. you could just filter them before setting them to state.

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare the following state:

```
const [investmentsIds, setInvestmentIds] = useState([]);
```

Add few more lines of code here:

```
investService.fetchUserSaveInvestments().then((res) => {
   setSaveCards(res.data);
   let savedCardIds = [];
   /* push investment_id in an array */
   res.data.forEach((value)=>{
       savedCardIds.push(value.investments_id);
   })
   setInvestmentIds(savedCardIds);
});
```

Your JSX:

```
<div className={classes.CardsContainer}>
   <div className={classes.CardsSelector}>
       {loading && <p> its loading </p>}
       {!loading && (
          {cards.map((card) => (
            {investmentsIds.includes(card.id) && 
              <Card {...card}
              handleClick={() => handleChooseCard(card)}/>
            }
          ))}
       )}
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using a `Set` to keep track of the *saved* card IDs since it provides *O(1)* time complexity lookups (fast, better than searching another array for each filter candidate).

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
const [cards, setCards] = useState([])
const [saveCards, setSaveCards] = useState(new Set())

useEffect(async () => {
  setLoading(true);

  const { data: savedCards } = await investService.fetchUserSaveInvestments()
  const savedCardIds = savedCards.map(({ investments_id }) => investments_id)
  setSaveCards(new Set(savedCardIds))

  const { data: { investments: cards } } = await investService.fetchCards()
  setCards(cards)
  setLoading(false)
}, [])
```

You can then use a *memo* to do the filtering

```js
const myCards = useMemo(() => cards.filter(({ id }) => !saveCards.has(id)), [cards, saveCards])
```

```
{myCards.map(card => (
  <Card
    {...card}
    handleClick={() => handleChooseCard(card)}
  />
))}
```